# Oven baked cashews taste good but not cripy

Tags: roasting, nuts

I tried roasting cashews twice. The first time i added tamari sauce (just a savoury soy sauce) and roasted them. The tamari got a little burned but overall the taste was good.

Except the nuts were not cripsy of crunchy, not rubbery per se but just not the expected 'brittle-nes' of roasted nuts.

Next time I was inspired by [this](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17582/how-to-salt-and-roast-pistachios/57609#57609) and [this receipe](https://slate.com/culture/2014/05/roasted-cashews-recipe-and-why-you-should-soak-nuts.html), to soak the nuts in salty water with some lemon juice prior to draining, seasoning and roasting them. (Which again added both flavour and moisture to the nuts) The nuts tasted good but were not crispy.

How do i get my oven-roasted cashews salty and crispy?

EDIT: Tried the same with almonds with similar results. Soaked them for 2 hours in water, lemon juice and tamari sauce (soy-sauce). Then roasted them for 25 mins at about 150degrees. Taste good but no crisp.

Comment: I'm not sure cashews will get crispy, they are a rather soft nut to begin with.  Have you had crispy cashews?

Comment: The tamari cashew i buy are crispier - in my memory anyway. Have not tried them side-by-side. Maybe i should try the same receipes with almonds.

Comment: Is this in an oven, and if so, is it a gas or electric oven?  Burning most hydrocarbons (eg, natural gas, propane, etc.) produces water which may hinder your attempts to dry them out fully.

Comment: @Joe Its an electric oven.

Comment: Have you tried roasting them in a dry pan instead of an oven?

Comment: @JohnW. Not yet, that will be the next experiment.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, cashews are a softer nut(seed) than other nuts to begin with. Soaking cashews is recommended when you are using them in a recipe where you want them to be smooth and creamy, therefore, soaking them might be your problem. Try just roasting them without soaking beforehand.